# No led indicator on Volume/mute buttons on keyboard

Tags: 18.04, backlight

As stated in the question, I have no light coming through my volume or mic buttons on my Thinkpad x230's backlit keyboard. Rest of the keyboard is working fine. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It is worth noting that the power button does light up.